# How to convert a nonstandard expression to form $(x-b)^2$

Tags: factoring

I want to convert the expression $x(−e_c^2+1)(x+2ae_c)$ into form $(x−b)^2$, where $a$ does not have any $x$ in it. I've tried converting them with completing the square, but I always get at least one term with an $x$ in it. Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it, and what should my result be?

Comment: It is not possible for two such expressions to be equal unless $e_c = a = 0$.

Comment: Completing the square will give you something like $(x-a)^2+b$.

Comment: @hardmath It is just an expression, not an equation.

Comment: You asked about "converting" two expressions, $x(−e_c^2+1)(x+2ae_c)$ and $(x-a)^2$. My point about these not being equal unless $e_c = a = 0$ is meant to help you understand why "completing the square" fails to accomplish such a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that "convert" as used in the title and body of the Question means rewriting one (polynomial) expression as another, of the form $(x-b)^2$, so that the two expressions are equal as (polynomial) functions over the domain of real numbers.

It is not possible unless $b=e_c=0$.  One way to see this is that $(x-b)^2$ has a double root at $x=b$ (and no other root).  Since $x(−e_c^2+1)(x+2ae_c)$ has at least one root at $x=0$, these expressions can be equal as polynomial functions only if:

$$ b = 0 \;\text{ and }\; 2ae_c = 0 $$

so that we then get a double root at $x=b=0$ for *both* expressions, and no other roots of either expression.  Furthermore we would need the leading coefficient to be one:

$$ −e_c^2+1 = 1 $$

so that both expressions are *monic* polynomials.

Taken together these conditions are satisfied exactly when $b = e_c = 0$ (and it doesn't matter what $a$ is since it is multiplied by zero).

Answer (score 0):

$$x(−e_c^2+1)(x+2ae_c)=  (−e_c^2+1)(x^2+2ae_cx)= (−e_c^2+1)((x+ae_c)^2-1) $$

Comment: This answer is not of the form $(x-a)^2$.

Comment: @FTL's account will be deleted : it could not be written completely as you want.

Comment: @FTL's account will be deleted : is there something more about $e_c$

Comment: $e_c$ is just an unspecified constant, while I have edited the question so that it is of form $(x-b)^2$.